Is there anyway to compile a Rust program without a dependency on a libc for Linux?
Is there anyway I could compile a Rust program to a binary which does not depend on a libc for runtime and for Linux?

You can't compile Rust without dependency on some libc. But you can statically link musl with your Rust program and therefore you won't need an external libc for your Rust program to run. musl should work on any kernel newer than 2.6.39:

Linux 2.6.39 or later is believed to be sufficient; earlier versions in the 2.6 series will work, but with varying degrees of non-conformance, particularly in the area of signal handling behavior and close-on-exec race conditions. https://musl.libc.org/doc/1.1.24/manual.html


This answer would be better if you also explained how to statically link with musl, i.e. what should be installed, what should be put in Cargo.toml and/or .cargo/config and what commands to run for building.
